# Pixel 6 can't access certain websites on wifi, but the Pixel 3 works fine

Tags: wi-fi, ipv6, google-pixel-6

My Pixel 6 can't connect to a few domains like api.reddit.com, api.bitwarden.com, WSJ images, etc. I'm using [PingTool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.streamsoft.pingtools&hl=en_US&gl=US) to run `ping` and `tracert` to certain domains.

| Phone | Domain | Network | DNS | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pixel 3 | api.reddit.com: DNS -> IPv4 | home wifi | 203.0.113.2, 203.0.113.3 | ✅ |
| Pixel 3 | api.reddit.com: 151.101.57.140, IPv4 direct | home wifi | 203.0.113.2, 203.0.113.3 | ✅ |
| Pixel 3 | api.reddit.com: 2a04:4e42::200::396, IPv6 direct | home wifi | 203.0.113.2, 203.0.113.3 | ❌ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: DNS -> IPv6 | T-mobile | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: 151.101.57.140, IPv4 direct | T-mobile | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: 2a04:4e42::200::396, IPv6 direct | T-mobile | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: DNS -> IPv4, before IPv6 kicks in 30 seconds later | home wifi | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: DNS -> IPv6 | home wifi | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ❌ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: 151.101.57.140, IPv4 direct | home wifi | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: 2a04:4e42::200::396, IPv6 direct | home wifi | 203.0.113.1, 203.0.113.2 | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: DNS -> IPv4 | gym wifi | ? | ✅ |
| Pixel 6 | api.reddit.com: 151.101.57.140, IPv4 direct | gym wifi | ? | ✅ |

There's something going on with IPv6 DNS and it affects a number of sites: Reddit, WSJ, Fitbit, etc. How do I disable IPv6 for wifi? Most of the instructions I've found only apply to mobile networks.

Comment: Disable ipv6 on your router.